# In QGIS, How to add the database connection in DB Manager via Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, postgis-2.0, dbmanager

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.0.2

I want to add connection settings in DB Manager  via Python script. is it possible ? (I am interested in PostGIS and Oracle Spatial for now)

This script will save the connection setting (except the username and password) and the db manager will reflect the added connection in the respective list

Note: I can use psycopg2 or QGIS native lib but my requirements are to use the default already available tools only.

Comment: This may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256401/how-to-add-a-new-database-connection-to-qgis-with-python, but you need Qt5 in QGIS 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new database connection to QGIS with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256401/how-to-add-a-new-database-connection-to-qgis-with-python)