# Create and access a permanent connection in PostgreSQL using PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to create a automatic connection from a QGIS Plugin to a PostgreSQL database and do manipulations like importing and exporting from the schemas.

I've found that you can use [QgsProviderRegistry](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsProviderRegistry.html#qgis.core.QgsProviderRegistry) and [QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.tables) to get access to the Schemas ([Getting table names from PostGIS database in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415101/getting-table-names-from-postgis-database-in-pyqgis?rq=1)):

```py
## CHECK SCHEMAS
md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres')
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
# Important to keep postgres as 3rd argument or will not work
uri.setConnection(localhost, "5432", db_name, username, password)
conn = md.createConnection(uri.uri(), {})
#print(conn)

for sch in conn.schemas():
    print(sch)
```

But this created connection seems temporary:

[image: output-console]

[image: browser]

I've searched the documentation to understand better this question. But didn't discovered much.

---

Looking over [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348833/loading-postgis-layer-from-sql-query-using-pyqgis) and using a test Table (shape)

[image: table]

[image: output-console1]

Didn't worked as expected.

[image: unavailable layer]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461589/51035

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QGIS provide a plugin to import|export data from a PostgresSQL database.

In QGIS 3.30 , calling this plugin result in this code :

```
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri
from db_manager.dlg_import_vector import DlgImportVector
from db_manager.db_plugins.postgis.plugin import PostGisDBPlugin, PGDatabase
from configparser import ConfigParser

services = ConfigParser()
services.read(os.environ['PGSERVICEFILE'] if 'PGSERVICEFILE' in os.environ else os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.pg_service.conf'))

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(services, dbname, '', '')
dbplugin = PostGisDBPlugin(dbname)
db = PGDatabase(dbplugin, uri)
dlg = DlgImportVector(None, db, uri, None)
```

This give access to the plugin directly set on the given database, but you need a good pg_service.conf file in your user space to make it work properly

https://docs.postgresql.fr/10/libpq-pgservice.html

Another example that directly load a layer from the db to the QGIS project.
With the good imports and layer_name being the name of the layer in QGIS, table_name the name of the table in the given schema of the db. We also do a small job to look if a 'work' group exist , create it if not and add the layer to it.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
if root.findGroup('work') :
      work_group = root.findGroup('work')
else :
      work_group = root.addGroup('work')

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(services, dbname, '', '')
uri.setDataSource('work', table_name, str(column_geom))

layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layer_name, "postgres")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
work_group.addLayer(layer)
QgsProject.instance().write(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
```

This has changed a bit for some QGIS version, but with a bit of documentation and theses examples it should be possible. If you produce correct code, you can answer and close this.

Answer (score 0):

As presented by @Maximilien the code works, but I've made slight changes due to some mentioned QGIS modifications such as `tr(layer_name)` to just `layer_name` and the `setConnection()` method.

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from db_manager.dlg_import_vector import DlgImportVector
from db_manager.db_plugins.postgis.plugin import PostGisDBPlugin, PGDatabase
from configparser import ConfigParser
###
services = ConfigParser()
services.read(os.environ['PGSERVICEFILE'] if 'PGSERVICEFILE' in os.environ else os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.pg_service.conf'))

dbname = 'projeto1_sl'  # Replace with the appropriate service name from the pg_service.conf file
table_name = 'test'  # Replace with the name of your table
layer_name = 'db_test'  # Replace with the desired layer name
schema_name = 'prj_test'  # Replace with the desired schema name

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
if root.findGroup('db'):
    work_group = root.findGroup('db')
else:
    work_group = root.addGroup('db')

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(
    services.get(dbname, 'host'),
    services.get(dbname, 'port'),
    services.get(dbname, 'dbname'),
    services.get(dbname, 'user'),
    services.get(dbname, 'password')
)
uri.setDataSource(schema_name, table_name, 'geom')


layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layer_name, "postgres")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
work_group.addLayer(layer)
QgsProject.instance().write(QgsProject.instance().fileName())

print('end')
```

But **one thing still troubles me, is the permanency of the connection**, this method brings the desired query if I add a point (tested) it updates the table in the server.

[image]

The `test` was the exported layer to the dataset and `db_test`was the result of the script, so as mentioned, I've added a new feature and the server table is updated:

[image]

But if I go to the Browser Pannel,at the PostgreSQL tab or in the Data Source Manager, **the recent connection isn't there**, where is it stored?

[image]

Comment: The connection is created with code when calling QgsDataSourceUri. But if you want to have it as a preset connection in Qgis UI, it's something else, you need to store connection parameters in Qgis ... so maybe look at the doc

Comment: Please keep your questions in the main question and don't accept an answer until satisfied. I am searching for the same info as you currently and this was super confusing to read through :)

Comment: @bugmenot123 sorry about that, I've found that the connection is wil the provider of the shape, I've asked for a way to create this connection an to this, Max answers works, but additionaly I'm looking for a permanent register in the Postgre provider menu. If you find any answwer feel free to send a mensage, I'll do the same once I find :D